# Как организовать работу telethon вступателя в чаты с ссылками, которые имеют + в хеше или с буквенным хешем?

Tags: python

Telethon отлично работает и вступает в чаты телеграмм ссылка которых выглядит так

```
https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAAAAAAA
client(ImportChatInviteRequest('AAAAAAAAAA'))
```

А как сделать, чтобы он смог вступать ещё и в чаты типа:

```
https://t.me/topchat
```

ИЛИ

```
https://t.me/+ААААААА
```

Именно с ссылками, которые имеют + в начале или "словесный" хеш возникают проблемы и телетон пишет,что якобы такого чата нет.

> telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.InviteHashExpiredError: The chat the user tried to join has expired and is not valid anymore

Как её решить?

Answer (score 0):

В документации есть отличный пример как вступать в публичные чаты - telethonn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/examples/chats-and-channels.html

Но ссылку со знаком "+", если я не ошибаюсь не так давно добавили, и скорее разработчики ещё не успели, обновить библиотеку.